# How to connect to and populate SQL database using Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I want to write an application that talks to a database. The databases are created through phpmyadmin interface. I can talk to these fine through php. What I would like is to populate these databases using a powershell script.

How do I connect to the database ? How do I populate a database ? I can't seem to find any good starting points.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @JanezKuhar i take it that means 'DatabaseManagementSystem' ? I've never worked server side before so all this is new to me. All I know is I have wampserver installed on my machine, and I created a database through phpmyadmin

Comment: That's what I meant, yeah. I don't know [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) but it says on their web page that they're using MySQL. You can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173988/use-mysql-console-through-a-powershell-script) question. This is in a way a duplicate question.

Comment: @JanezKuhar that looks spot on, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function to handle this type of task

```
function Invoke-SQL
{
param (
    [string]$server,
    [string]$database,
    [string]$Query
)

$connectionString = "Data Source=$server; " +
"Integrated Security=SSPI; " +
"Initial Catalog=$database"

$connection = new-object 
system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
$command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($Query, $connection)
$connection.Open()

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command

# Use these to populate info #
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

$connection.Close()

# displays info #
$dataSet.Tables
}
```

Here's an example of updating the SQL Database

```
Invoke-SQL -server 'server' -database 'database' -Query "UPDATE [database].[dbo].[Local] SET Field1 = '$InfoForField1', Field2 = '$InfoForField2'"
```

You can do whatever you need using this method, as long as you know your SQL queries and how to populate the varaibles with the correct information that you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great place to start: 
https://dbatools.io/
https://dbareports.io/

or you can look here as well: 
https://www.powershellgallery.com/

Comment: The best SQL people I know recommend https://dbatools.io for managing SQL databases. I upvoted this even if it is an answer with just a link to other sites.

Comment: If the poster had included some code I'd have been happy to add to it.