# Running MySQL query in PowerShell script

Tags: mysql, powershell

I want to write SQL queries in a PowerShell script to run them with Task Scheduler later.

```
$db   = 'hotels'
$user = 'root'
$pass = ''

$mysql  = 'C:\mariadb\mariadb-10.3.12-winx64\bin\mysql.exe'
$params = '-u', $user, $db

& $mysql @params -e 'SELECT user FROM ondemandscheduledrequests ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1' hotels

Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
```

I tried a simple one like this.

When I performed a `SELECT *` query it worked fine, but when I try to retrieve a single field, I have this displayed:

[image: mysql.exe output]

I don't understand why it is not working.

Comment: what is that `hotels` at the end ?

Comment: The spurious trailing "hotels" aside, using the commandline utility is not recommended. Please see the latter half of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40182282/1630171).

Comment: it is the name of my table